# Not getting the expression value in the table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am new to `angularjs`. So , I have a `contextmenu` for the table data.

```
<div contextmenu-container="meta.contextmenu">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table" fixed-header>
            <thead class="text-center text-info">
            <th class="text-center">Annotation</th>
            <th class="text-center">Field</th>
            <th class="text-center">Message</th>
            <th class="text-center">Score</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
              <td class="td-report-field" contextmenu-item="row">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" 
                ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                  {{ report.attributes.message }}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
              <div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu ">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content" role="menu">
                  <li>
                      <a role="menu" href
                      data-ng-click="deleteAnnotation(report.attributes.field)">
                      <span>delete</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
```

In this,when I try to use the `report.attributes.field in the deleteAnnotation` method then It gives `undefined` . So,How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get each repeated object inside '$itemScope'.
In your case it will be '$itemScope.report', after that you can perform whatever operations you want on that data.

In angular contextmenu , "meta.contextmenu.item" will point to "contextmenu-item". Hope this helps.

### [ui bootstrap contextmenu](https://jsbin.com/zorusikabu/edit?html,js,output)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="HelloWorldApp" class='container'>
    <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
      <table class='table table-striped'>
          <tr>
            <td><b>NAME</b></td>
            <td><b>ADDRESS</b></td>
          </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in objects" >
          <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
          <td context-menu="menuOptions">{{obj.address}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div ng-bind="selected"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', ['ui.bootstrap.contextMenu'])
   .controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
  $scope.objects = [{
    name: 'person1',
    address: 'India'
  },
  {
    name: 'any name',
    address: 'any address'
  }];
  $scope.menuOptions = [
    ['Select', function ($itemScope, $event, modelValue, text, $li) {
        $scope.selected = $itemScope.obj.address;
    }]
];
});
```

### [angular-contextmenu](https://jsbin.com/boyusoliwa/edit?html,js,output)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="HelloWorldApp" class='container'>
    <div ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
      <div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
      {{ meta.contextmenu.item.address }}
    </li>

    <li>
      <a role="menuitem" href
        ng-click="delete(meta.contextmenu.item)"
      >
        <span>Delete</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

      <table class='table table-striped' contextmenu-container="meta.contextmenu">
          <tr>
            <td><b>NAME</b></td>
            <td><b>ADDRESS</b></td>
          </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in objects" contextmenu-item="obj" >
          <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
          <td context-menu="menuOptions">{{obj.address}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      Data  to delete : 
      <pre>{{selected.name}}</pre>
      <pre>{{selected.address}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('HelloWorldApp', ['io.dennis.contextmenu'])
   .controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
       $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
  $scope.objects = [{
    name: 'person1',
    address: 'India'
  },
  {
    name: 'any name',
    address: 'any address'
  }];
  $scope.delete = function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.selected = data;
  }
});
```

**you will need to include necessary libs for ui-bootstrap contextmenu and/or angular contextmenu 
** And again, sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: This one is good but I am not using the directive which u have used. I am using angular-contextmenu

Comment: please refer link2

Comment: Please don't put links to JSBin in code blocks to evade the automatic filter—include the code **in the post itself** in case the link breaks in future. Posts which are only links to external sources may be deleted, so please [edit] before that happens.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15864204)

Comment: @Christoph and all others,  Thanks for the review, I have added code blocks, but formatting is messed up. This is my 1st time posting on stackoverflow, and thanks again for reviewing.

Comment: Awadhoot, this is a really good answer. Please take your time to give your answers nice formatting to improve the value even more - you will also get more upvotes this way! Simply have a look at my edit to see, how good formatting can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `deleteAnnotation` after ending `<tr>` which has the **ng-repeat**

The variable `report` is in the `ng-repeat` scope so u need to call the `deleteAnnotation` function inside `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
              <td class="td-report-field" contextmenu-item="row">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" 
                ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                  {{ report.attributes.message }}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
            </tr>
```

Here the scope is ended.

So you cannot access `report`

Also do not embed `div` in `table` tag

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table" fixed-header>
                <thead class="text-center text-info">
                <th class="text-center">Annotation</th>
                <th class="text-center">Field</th>
                <th class="text-center">Message</th>
                <th class="text-center">Score</th>
                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>
                  <td class="td-report-field" contextmenu-item="row">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" 
                    ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                    <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                      {{ report.attributes.message }}
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
                  <td>
<div contextmenu="meta.contextmenu" class="dropdown contextmenu ">
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content" role="menu">
                      <li>
                          <a role="menu" href="#"
                          data-ng-click="deleteAnnotation(report.attributes.field)">
                          <span>delete</span>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Try this. Also check report has a `attributes.field` property in that loop.

Comment: Now I am calling it in tr but still I am not able to get the value.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (contextmenu.js:194)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4121)

Comment: @ganeshk what is `contextmenu="meta.contextmenu"`, try to remove this and run again

Comment: Here, I have added a angular-context menu for the second column data.

Comment: try printing `{{report}}` and check whether it has data

Comment: I think it's like you can not use {{report.attributes.field}} in div but u have to use it in the <td> tag ?

Comment: no, u can use it. You should have a very basic understanding on angular